# UNET ID Unity 5.4

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am working on a Unity Multiplayer Networking App.  I've gotten to that point where I can successfully run a client and host on the same machine.  However, when I run the host on one machine and have the client on another machine try and connect to it, the client is unable to connect.  It searches until it times out.

I've found people who have run into similar problems, and I've found an answer here that suggested obtaining a Unity UNET ID.  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/990419/how-to-use-unity-51-networking-on-multiple-compute.html#answer-1064955

However, the link in that answer is now broken, and I can't find any information on obtaining a UNET ID for a Unity 5.4 app.  Does anybody have any experience successfully doing cross-computer multiplayer networking with Unity 5.4?

Comment: why not connecting? is this port issue?

Comment: Encountering the same problem.  Research dead-ended here. :(